# Combinatorics Game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

Initially there is 1 stone on top of every unit square of the m*n-sized board. Outside the board there was an infinite supply of stones. Andy plays using the board and stones as follows: each step, Andy can choose one of 3 moves:

1. Select a non-empty square that is not in the leftmost column. take one stone from the square and place 2 stones in the square to the left
2. Select a non-empty square that is not in the bottom row. take one stone from the square and place 2 stones in the square below it
3. Select 2 adjacent non-empty squares. Take one stone from the 2 unit squares

prove that Andy can take all the stones if and only if m*n is even

I've tried using invariant but stuck.

Comment: A naive attempt would be to start at the right edge.  Remove each stone in that column and replace it with two stones in the column to the left.  The right column is now empty and will never get another stone.  Keep going until all the stones are in the left column.  Now start from the top and take the top stone.  This will leave an enormous pile of stones in the lower left, which you cannot remove so this fails.

Comment: We need to leave stones in the left two columns.  Assume there is an even number of columns-otherwise transpose.  Explain why you can leave the same number of stones in each square of the left two columns, then remove all the stones

Comment: Sorry i think i need to edit the qiestion

Comment: I don't think the question is correct. Note that the total number of stones on the board always increases, so it's sounds very weird that the board can be cleared.

Comment: Not always, if i have mn even i can hse move 3 repeatedly to clear the board.

Comment: How many stones are removed by move 3? Is it one stone chosen from among the two squares (total stones removed = 1)? Or is it one stone from each of the two squares (total stones removed = 2)?

Comment: @SlipEternal It must be one stone per square. If it only removed one stone in total, then the total number of stones over the board would never go lower than one (because move 3 needs at least two stones).

Answer (score 3):

Let's index the rows from $0$ to $n-1$ from bottom to top, and index the columns from $0$ to $m-1$ from left to right.

Then we say a single stone on the square $(i,j)$ has cost $2^{i+j}$, then the total cost of the board at the start is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} 2^{i+j} = (2^n-1)(2^m-1) \equiv nm-2\left\lfloor\frac{nm}{2}\right\rfloor \pmod3$. Then any moves of type $1$ and $2$ has $0$ effect on this total cost. For any move of type $3$, it will decrease this cost by $2^k + 2^{k+1}$ for some $k\in Z, 0\le k< n+m-2$. Also $2^k + 2^{k+1} = 3\cdot2^k \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

So you can take the invariant of the total cost$\mod 3$, and use it to show that the invariant never gets to zero which is the cost of the final state.